# Where can I find Generic.xaml for universal apps

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm looking for the complete Generic.xaml for Universal apps.

Currently I've located these two on my PC for Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Store 8.1:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\Include\abi\Xaml\Design\Generic.xaml
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt\xaml\design\Generic.xaml
```

Can someone point me in the right direction with where to find the shared generic.xaml and maybe even some documentation on MSDN on this?

Comment: Are you just looking for the default templates of all your controls etc? Whenever in doubt, just right-click whatever it is, then Edit Template->Edit Current, Blend is extra handy for this.

Comment: I was looking for the actual files used in Universal apps - I believed they merged the generic.xaml into one file, which was a mistake to believe so. Furthermore I wanted to modify the default templates for the controls without going into creating resource dictionaries with custom styles. This is not possible in universal apps at this moment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**
*The files referred above is actually the ones used by Universal apps for standard styling. However it's important to note that these can't be overwritten by using a modified version of the file included in the project in a folder named themes, nor by creating a normal resourcedictionary and here in create resources using the same key.*

Comment: That's incorrect amigo, you can copy your res dicts, or styles to your own, or whatever you want. Then just go find where the default pointers are in the default dict (the <Style TargetType="blah" BasedOn="{StaticResource blah}"/>) and cut them and paste them in your res dict to point to your own, as long as you have your mergeddictionaries declarations setup correct, you can do it all day long.

Comment: My point was that I wanted to avoid exactly that. What I wanted to do was copy the generic.xaml into my solution and modify it and have that working as a replacement for the builtin Generic.xaml. And since we are talking about Generic.xaml, it shouldn't be merged in app.xaml. 
What I wanted to achieve was e.g. changing the ApplicationBackgroundThemeBrush to Red in Generic.xaml, and then have that override the built in styles.

Comment: Yea but you have to remember what you're working in is based more on silverlight than WPF